# Trying to get custom post meta through Jetpack JSON API

Tags: post-meta, api, plugin-jetpack, json

I'm using the Jetpack for Wordpress to produce a JSON API for my **Events** custom post type, which works fine:

`https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/MYSITE/posts/?type=events&number=100`

However, this CPT also includes quite a few Post Meta Fields generated by [Custom Meta Boxes and Fields for Wordpress](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress). These fields include things like:

- `_ecmb_supporting_bands`
- `_ecmb_tickets_avail`
- `_ecmb_event_agelim`

And by default these fields aren't returned by the JSON API... I've tried to run queries like:

`https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/MYSITE/posts/?type=events&number=100&meta_key='_ecmb_supporting_bands'`

Or without quotes around the meta key:
`https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/MYSITE/posts/?type=events&number=100&meta_key=_ecmb_supporting_bands`

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can return these custom meta fields in my JSON response?

Comment: This is a Jetpack/WordPress.com question, you need to ask a .com/jetpack support forum or contact Automattic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### From the documentation:

According to the [JetPack JSON API docs](http://developer.wordpress.com/2013/04/26/custom-post-type-and-metadata-support-in-the-rest-api/):

> By default, all metadata keys are allowed in the API, as long as they
>   are not protected keys. Any metadata key that starts with _ is by
>   default protected. Protected metadata keys can, however, be accessed
>   and edited by users with the edit_post_meta (used for editing and
>   viewing), add_post_meta and delete_post_meta capabilities as
>   appropriate for each operation. We’ve also added a filter
>   rest_api_allowed_public_metadata that allows you to specifically
>   whitelist certain metadata keys to be accessed by any user, even if
>   that key is protected.

so the `rest_api_allowed_public_metadata` filter is what you are looking for.

### From the source code:

If you check the JetPack's source code, you will find this part:

```
    function is_metadata_public( $key ) {
            if ( empty( $key ) )
                    return false;

            // whitelist of post types that can be accessed
            if ( in_array( $key, apply_filters( 'rest_api_allowed_public_metadata', array() ) ) )
                    return true;

            return false;
    }
```

in the file `class.json-api-endpoints.php`.

You can also check out the `allow_bbpress_public_metadata()` function [here](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/jetpack/trunk/class.jetpack-bbpress-json-api-compat.php#L35) to see how to implement this `rest_api_allowed_public_metadata` filter.

### Example:

Here is a similar example for your case:

```
/**
 * Whitelist protected meta keys
 *
 * @param array $allowed_meta_keys 
 * @return array $allowed_meta_keys 
 */
function custom_rest_api_allowed_public_metadata( $allowed_meta_keys )
{
    // only run for REST API requests
    if ( ! defined( 'REST_API_REQUEST' ) || ! REST_API_REQUEST )
        return $allowed_meta_keys;

    $allowed_meta_keys[] = '_ecmb_supporting_bands';
    $allowed_meta_keys[] = '_ecmb_tickets_avail';
    $allowed_meta_keys[] = '_ecmb_event_agelim';

    return $allowed_meta_keys;
}

add_filter( 'rest_api_allowed_public_metadata', 'custom_rest_api_allowed_public_metadata' );
```

with the JSON output similar to this one:

```
"metadata":[{"id":"196711","key":"_ecmb_event_agelim","value":"18"},
            {"id":"196709","key":"_ecmb_supporting_bands","value":"The Rolling Stones"}, 
            {"id":"196710","key":"_ecmb_tickets_avail","value":"5500"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @birgire reply, placing the filter code somewhere can be tricky:

- If you place it under your theme's "functions.php" file, a theme update could overwrite your code
- Writing a plugin for just adding a filter is a lot of fuzz

This is why what I did was to use the following plugin that allows you to write your custom actions and filters within Wordpress admin panel without having to worry about losing it. http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-actions-and-filters/ .

I had the same problem than you and after including the filter now it works like a charm.